# Add Product Images (Not Thumbnails) to WooCommerce Order Emails

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am able to add product thumbnails to WooCommerce Order Emails, by modifing the file `email-order-details.php` and changing the `show_image` to `true`. (By following instructions: [here](https://nicola.blog/2016/02/02/show-the-product-thumbnail-in-woocommerce-emails/)).

But resolution of these thumbnails are very low. So I don't want thumbnails, but the original product image will be much better.

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

from the post that you mentioned in your Question 
you can change the picture size in the array

```
<?php echo $order->email_order_items_table( array(
    'show_sku'      => $sent_to_admin,
    'show_image'    => false,
    'image_size'   => array( 100, 100 ),
    'plain_text'    => $plain_text,
    'sent_to_admin' => $sent_to_admin
) ); ?>
```

as you can see i changed line 4: `'image_size' => array( 100, 100 ),` to change the image size to `100px X 100px`, normally you can use `full`, `medium` too.

Comment: Hi, it did not work. Can you give a reference link to this kind of usage? I couldn't find any resources online.

Comment: @HOY i've changed my answer, try this one and see if it works.

Comment: I know how to change the size of the image actually, this is not my question.  Because the resolution of thumbnails is very low, and it only makes the thumbnail bigger which results in a very low quality image. This is why the question asks about changing the image, not the image size.